# Spring boot configuration profiles

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I trying to implement an application that has the ability to switch two different databases at runtime using .properties configuration file.So, according to the configuration file, only one data source should create and also there are have axon framework configuration and repositories for each data source.
I'm already using spring boot,spring jpa,spring mongodb and axon framework.

I want to load one configuration (mysql,mongo) at runtime.So are there any scenario to do it in Spring boot.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

## [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it be available only in certain environments.

The actual example they use switches out `hsqldb` with `proddb`.

Then you can [set the Active Spring Profiles at runtime.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

The Spring/Spring Boot documentation is on the whole, very good. You should bookmark it.